# В чем разница пакетов javax и jakarta?

Tags: java, maven, servlet, tomcat

Когда импортирую классы пакета jaсarta(когда создаю новый проект по умолчанию импортируются они), маппинг сервлета не работает и в браузере вылетает ошибка 404, а когда импортирую вместо них javax, работает.Подскажите пожалуйста в чем причина? Прикрепляю скрины:
[image: тут маппинг не работает]

[image: а тут работает]

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## jakarta и javax

Ранее Java состояла из:

- Java SE (Standart Edition)
- Java EE (Enterprise Edition)

В последнем содержались наборы спецификаций и документация для языка Java, описывающей архитектуру серверной платформы для разработки Enterprise приложений.

Соответственно реализации Java EE содержали и пакет `javax`.
После поглащения Sun Microsystems  корпорацией Oracle, последняя отказалась от поддержки Java EE.
Развитием и поддержкой последнего занялось сообщество с компании, использующие данные технологии.
Но так как `Java` является зарегистрированной торговой маркой - разработчикам, поддерживающим реализации Java EE, пришлось переименовать часть пакетов во избежания исков со стороны Oracle.
И jakarta - одна из реализаций Java EE

Вот и весь сказ.

- Старые пакеты и реализации  - javax.*
- Новые - jakarta.*, etc

## Что подключать

С одной стороны кажется что все одно и тоже и нет разницы что именно подключать.
**Но то не так!**
У Вас должен быть подключен пакет, который совместим с версией вашего сервера приложений.

логика та же

Старые версии сервера приложений - javax
Новые - jakarta, etc

Чтобы не гадать - можете посмотреть зависимости сервера приложений и подключить ту же у себя в приложении.

*(если приложите версию сервера приложений - могу предложить что именно подключать)*

Comment: Tomcat 9.0.65 . Получается оба пакета Tomcat предоставляет?

Comment: да, Старые версии сервера приложений - javax Новые - jakarta, etc

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: После какого Tomcat javax перестаёт работать и нужен пакет jakarta?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev, с 10ой версии, если мне не изменяет память. И не перестает работать, а просто имеет другую реализацию Java EE

Comment: @МихаилРебров Десятый Tomcat. У меня почему-то ошибка 500 из-за этого импорта: `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`. Говорю, из-за него, потому что если его убрать (и строчки кода, которые от него зависят), то вью отображается. Не могу понять, что не так с ним. Зависимость в pom такая: `org.glassfish.web.jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl`

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev JSTL нужно подключить в зависимостях... у меня где-то был ответ на эту тему

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev добавьте в dependencies `<dependency<groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId><artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId><version>2.0.0</version></dependency>`

Comment: @МихаилРебров У меня и такая зависимость была (только более новая версия, 3.0.0). Если только она одна, то `forEach` вообще не находится. Рискну задать вопрос, пожалуй 