# 404 ошибка; GlassFish; сервлеты

Tags: servlet, http-status-code-404, glassfish

При попытке обратиться к сервлету по адресу localhost:61687/hello (или ему подобному)  я получаю ошибку 404.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Подробности:**

Сам сервер работает, потому что по адресу http://localhost:61687/ появляется страничка, это подтверждающая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Порт 61687, т.к. 8080 занят.

.war файл собирал с помощью gradle командой

```
./gradle war
```

Сервер запускал из консоли следующей командой:

```
./asadmin start-domain newDomain1
```

Для деплоя использовал следующую команду

```
./asadmin deploy --force /Users/dima/Documents/projects/Java/JavaEE/build/libs/JavaEE-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
```

Код сервлета:

```
package servlets;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(name="firstservlet", urlPatterns = "/hello")
public class servlet1 extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter printWriter = resp.getWriter();
        printWriter.write("Hello!");
        printWriter.close();
    }
}
```

build.gradle файл:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
    compileOnly group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.servlet', version: '3.2-b06'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**Как пытался исправить ошибку**

Пробовал адрес http://localhost:61687/JavaEE-1.0-SNAPSHOT/hello - ситуация не изменилась.

Пробовал класс сервлета использовать без пакета

Пробовал использовать аннотацию с одним аргументом: @WebServlet("/hello")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С проблемой разобрался сам.
Как я понял, проблема могла заключаться в том, что я использовал **старую версию** сервлетов и **последнюю версию сервера** GlassFish 7.2.

На это меня надоумил вот этот вот вопрос [В чем разница пакетов javax и jakarta?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1434938/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-javax-%D0%B8-jakarta)

Таким образом, мой файл build.gradle стал выглядеть следующим образом:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
//    compileOnly group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.servlet', version: '3.2-b06'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api
    compileOnly group: 'jakarta.servlet', name: 'jakarta.servlet-api', version: '6.0.0'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

А импорты приняли следующий вид:

```
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
...
```